# Code Golf - Word Clock

Tags: code-golf

Write a program which takes the current time of the system clock, rounds to the nearest minute (you may choose how to round halves) and displays it formatted as the following:

```
A quarter past one in the morning.
A quarter to two in the afternoon.
Two o'clock in the afternoon.
Twenty-five minutes to three in the morning.
Twenty-seven minutes to seven in the evening.
One minute past twelve in the afternoon.
Twelve o'clock noon.
Twelve o'clock midnight.
```

Rules:

- 12:01am to 11:59am is deemed as morning.
- 12:01pm to 5:59pm is deemed as afternoon.
- 6:00pm to 11:59pm is deemed as evening.
- 15 minutes past the hour must be expressed as `A quarter past` the hour
- 30 minutes past the hour must be expressed as `Half past` the hour
- 45 minutes past the hour must be expressed as `A quarter to` the upcoming hour
- On-the-hour times must be expressed as the hour `o'clock`, with the addition of noon and midnight being expressed with the addition of `noon` or `midnight` respectively.
- Other times in hh:01 to hh:29 must be expressed as (number of minutes) `past` the hour.
- Other times in hh:31 to hh:59 must be expressed as (number of minutes) `to` the upcoming hour.
- Twenty-one to twenty-nine must be hyphenated.
- The first letter of the output must be capitalised. The other letters must be lower-case.

It would be useful to provide a testing version of your code so that it can be tested without manipulating the system clock.

Comment: *Let's see what you got...* - The specification is still a bit vague. E.g. what about `Fifteen minutes past one` or `Fourty-five minutes past one` for the first two examples?

Comment: I agree with Howard: there's a lot of dialectal variation here. To ensure that the contest is about golfing you need a complete spec. You also need to address rounding because the time is rarely an integer number of minutes past midnight.

Comment: What?  Noon is noon, and midnight is midnight.  I suggest those times read "Twelve o'clock noon" and "Twelve o'clock midnight".  Noon is *not* afternoon, or 0=1.

Comment: Okay, so what do I print at 3:30 PM? Do I have to say "half past three in the afternoon"?

Comment: I'm voting to close until the spec is clarified to avoid more people posting solutions which might have to be withdrawn for not meeting the clarified spec.

Comment: I join @PeterTaylor, and suggest passing it through [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/638/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-v)

Comment: @boothby As soon as a clock hits 12:00 noon, it registers as a PM time, as does a clock hitting 12:00 midnight registers as an AM time...

Comment: Any clock that exhibits that behavior sucks.  In my humble opinion or something.

Comment: so, "thirty minutes past twelve in the morning" is a valid output?

Comment: I thought I had put the 15,30,45 minute rules in...? They must have not saved... 

Updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Python 2.7, <s>159</s> <s>162</s> <s>156</s> 161

```
from datetime import*
n=datetime.now()
if n.hour()<12:
 t="morning"
elif n.hour()<18:
 t="afternoon"
else:
 t="evening"
print"%i in the %s."%(n.hour(),t)
```

**Edit #1** - Added a period at the end of the output.

**Edit #2** - Shortened the imports, lengthened code to correct syntax.

Comment: Why the verbosity in the print statement? You're calling `str` on... a string... anyway, much shorter: `print"%i in the %s."%(n.hour,t)` (and then you can remove the period from the other strings, saving even more chars

Comment: Attempting to test on ideone gives [syntax error](http://ideone.com/Yv1GNb). (I was attempted to test because on inspection this doesn't seem to meet the spec, regardless of how the current ambiguities are resolved).

Comment: Would be helpful to show an example with input and output.  Looks to me like numbers are rendered as digits rather than letter strings.

Comment: @DavidCarraher They are

Comment: @Tim, Did you read the spec? It needs to output the time in a written format as I mentioned above...

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio Okay, I'll work on it

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 450

`Date[]` calls for the current date and time. `[[{4,5}]]` returns the hour and minutes

```
f[]:=f[Date[][[{4,5}]]];
f[{h_,m_}]:=Module[{p,w,s},
p@h1_:=Which[0<h<12," in the morning.",12<h<18," in the afternoon.",18<h<24, " in the evening."];
s[t_]:=WolframAlpha["spell "<>ToString@t,{{"Result",1},"Plaintext"}];
w=s[h~Mod~12]<>p@h;
Which[
m==0, Switch[h,12, "noon", 0|24,"midnight",_,s[h~Mod~12]<>p@h],
m==15,"a quarter past "<>w,
m==30,"half past "<>w,
m==45,"a quarter to "<>s[h~Mod~12+1]<>p@h,
m<30,s@m<>" minutes after "<>w,
m>29,s[60-m]<>" minutes before "<>s[h~Mod~12+1]<>p@h]]
```

**Current Time**

```
f[]
```

> "ten minutes past three in the afternoon."

**Specific times**

```
f[{4, 45}]
f[{10, 30}]
f[{11, 0}]
f[{12, 0}]
f[{13, 15}]
f[{15, 0}]
f[{22, 17}]
f[{24, 0}]
```

> "a quarter to five in the morning."
> "half past ten in the morning."
> "eleven in the morning."
> "noon"
> "a quarter past one in the afternoon."
> "three in the afternoon."
> "seventeen minutes past ten in the evening."
> "midnight"

Comment: I noticed I still need to implement "minutes before midnight/noon" and "n minutes after midnight/noon". Will get to that later.

Comment: You can save a few characters and get in spec by using "to" rather than "before" and "past" rather than "after".