# Approximate when you are going to die

Tags: code-challenge, statistics, approximation

A mortality table or life table is an actuarial tool that gives the probability that a person aged \$A\$ years will die in the next year, and is used to help calculate the premiums for life insurance, among other things. One of the first people to compile a life table was [Edmond Halley](https://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/histstat/halley.pdf), of cometary fame. These probabilities also allow you to estimate the life expectancy for a given age, which is the goal of this challenge.

## Input

- An integer from 0 to 119, inclusive.
- An indicator for Sex M/F.

## Output

- An approximation for the life expectancy for that Age/Sex according to the [Social Security Administration's 2016 Mortality Table](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html), aka the Actuarial Life table, the relevant part of which can be found below.

```r
Age     M           F
0       75.97       80.96
1       75.45       80.39
2       74.48       79.42
3       73.50       78.43
4       72.52       77.45
5       71.53       76.46
6       70.54       75.47
7       69.55       74.47
8       68.56       73.48
9       67.57       72.49
10      66.57       71.50
11      65.58       70.50
12      64.59       69.51
13      63.60       68.52
14      62.61       67.53
15      61.63       66.54
16      60.66       65.55
17      59.70       64.57
18      58.74       63.59
19      57.79       62.61
20      56.85       61.63
21      55.91       60.66
22      54.98       59.69
23      54.06       58.72
24      53.14       57.75
25      52.22       56.78
26      51.31       55.82
27      50.39       54.85
28      49.48       53.89
29      48.56       52.93
30      47.65       51.97
31      46.74       51.01
32      45.83       50.06
33      44.92       49.10
34      44.01       48.15
35      43.10       47.20
36      42.19       46.25
37      41.28       45.30
38      40.37       44.36
39      39.47       43.41
40      38.56       42.47
41      37.65       41.53
42      36.75       40.59
43      35.85       39.66
44      34.95       38.73
45      34.06       37.80
46      33.17       36.88
47      32.28       35.96
48      31.41       35.04
49      30.54       34.13
50      29.67       33.23
51      28.82       32.33
52      27.98       31.44
53      27.14       30.55
54      26.32       29.68
55      25.50       28.81
56      24.70       27.94
57      23.90       27.09
58      23.12       26.24
59      22.34       25.39
60      21.58       24.56
61      20.83       23.72
62      20.08       22.90
63      19.35       22.07
64      18.62       21.26
65      17.89       20.45
66      17.18       19.65
67      16.47       18.86
68      15.77       18.07
69      15.07       17.30
70      14.39       16.54
71      13.71       15.79
72      13.05       15.05
73      12.40       14.32
74      11.76       13.61
75      11.14       12.92
76      10.53       12.23
77      9.94        11.57
78      9.37        10.92
79      8.82        10.29
80      8.28        9.68
81      7.76        9.09
82      7.26        8.52
83      6.79        7.98
84      6.33        7.45
85      5.89        6.95
86      5.48        6.47
87      5.08        6.01
88      4.71        5.57
89      4.37        5.16
90      4.05        4.78
91      3.75        4.43
92      3.48        4.11
93      3.23        3.81
94      3.01        3.55
95      2.81        3.31
96      2.64        3.09
97      2.49        2.90
98      2.36        2.73
99      2.24        2.58
100     2.12        2.42
101     2.01        2.28
102     1.90        2.14
103     1.80        2.01
104     1.70        1.88
105     1.60        1.76
106     1.51        1.65
107     1.42        1.54
108     1.34        1.44
109     1.26        1.34
110     1.18        1.24
111     1.10        1.15
112     1.03        1.06
113     0.96        0.98
114     0.90        0.91
115     0.84        0.84
116     0.78        0.78
117     0.72        0.72
118     0.66        0.66
119     0.61        0.61
```

For convenience, here they are in wide form (ages 0-119 in order):

```r
M: [75.97, 75.45, 74.48, 73.5, 72.52, 71.53, 70.54, 69.55, 68.56, 67.57, 66.57, 65.58, 64.59, 63.6, 62.61, 61.63, 60.66, 59.7, 58.74, 57.79, 56.85, 55.91, 54.98, 54.06, 53.14, 52.22, 51.31, 50.39, 49.48, 48.56, 47.65, 46.74, 45.83, 44.92, 44.01, 43.1, 42.19, 41.28, 40.37, 39.47, 38.56, 37.65, 36.75, 35.85, 34.95, 34.06, 33.17, 32.28, 31.41, 30.54, 29.67, 28.82, 27.98, 27.14, 26.32, 25.5, 24.7, 23.9, 23.12, 22.34, 21.58, 20.83, 20.08, 19.35, 18.62, 17.89, 17.18, 16.47, 15.77, 15.07, 14.39, 13.71, 13.05, 12.4, 11.76, 11.14, 10.53, 9.94, 9.37, 8.82, 8.28, 7.76, 7.26, 6.79, 6.33, 5.89, 5.48, 5.08, 4.71, 4.37, 4.05, 3.75, 3.48, 3.23, 3.01, 2.81, 2.64, 2.49, 2.36, 2.24, 2.12, 2.01, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.51, 1.42, 1.34, 1.26, 1.18, 1.1, 1.03, 0.96, 0.9, 0.84, 0.78, 0.72, 0.66, 0.61]
F: [80.96, 80.39, 79.42, 78.43, 77.45, 76.46, 75.47, 74.47, 73.48, 72.49, 71.5, 70.5, 69.51, 68.52, 67.53, 66.54, 65.55, 64.57, 63.59, 62.61, 61.63, 60.66, 59.69, 58.72, 57.75, 56.78, 55.82, 54.85, 53.89, 52.93, 51.97, 51.01, 50.06, 49.1, 48.15, 47.2, 46.25, 45.3, 44.36, 43.41, 42.47, 41.53, 40.59, 39.66, 38.73, 37.8, 36.88, 35.96, 35.04, 34.13, 33.23, 32.33, 31.44, 30.55, 29.68, 28.81, 27.94, 27.09, 26.24, 25.39, 24.56, 23.72, 22.9, 22.07, 21.26, 20.45, 19.65, 18.86, 18.07, 17.3, 16.54, 15.79, 15.05, 14.32, 13.61, 12.92, 12.23, 11.57, 10.92, 10.29, 9.68, 9.09, 8.52, 7.98, 7.45, 6.95, 6.47, 6.01, 5.57, 5.16, 4.78, 4.43, 4.11, 3.81, 3.55, 3.31, 3.09, 2.9, 2.73, 2.58, 2.42, 2.28, 2.14, 2.01, 1.88, 1.76, 1.65, 1.54, 1.44, 1.34, 1.24, 1.15, 1.06, 0.98, 0.91, 0.84, 0.78, 0.72, 0.66, 0.61]
```

## Scoring Rules

For this challenge, **the submission with the lowest score wins**. Your score will be equal to \$(1+L)\times(1 + M)\$, where \$L\$ is the length of your code in bytes and \$M\$ is the mean-squared error of your estimates, rounded to two decimal places. [This](https://tio.run/##dZTNalRBEIX39yka3RhIiv7/QXEjuBN8AmFMLiSgE5mZoD59POeUutJNF/d2V3XVqfr69PwjvLkJt69GszWuA0xtMNXqhCnGj2wtwyRrBSZaq9ehL2vY69Navw5bH9bg3rubZg3uvVpbMMVwpGfrCSZZR5QereNnW4bjW5s2ELMNGzjfuk2EbsgIDq3amjKRDsUST2bLSKklK4n@0Qoc61LW1XOqwzrC1K7YtdnEvRXRskyEY0U0uNdsie7JMt0RDEkVBKPxYMWDFQSjacqwIBjMVjy3gmj0yApTklUELy5XXtaxl6dNXJ@HaoJhMVvuVvi3Ue1cKUkutrQmbmQrjJGkao6qBCbiKy0rzCFN6ziahs0lk7jZVUNqNtxEmiqxUrGRZKL8s@GKlGx0GSaWojq@bFWuVMXzn6pw6OywrAFQ61AIHJpyaGpGU5ZVd1WFqLqwuJA6UywXyqieZJtaOyu2ShWsdK5ZfySITiZKlIx1aooSxwwaaatSDMmWlGByQUybEddFW10rl8k2RBuTHyNz7drlyE4/On3IxlLsMa2ShuG8QGiqQHyG4zOEjyjyMsiP4@P0JKcHsQgPBSA91elpTs8QPYLoP/h0Kj2V80Z@mvhhIeCHvQI4oql4U7KtInBIOwyFBD6c3w38JOGTmvDJoic30ePwsBOghpMNalhk9WcB1DDNDdgwM2AzirCZomZOUUMdYWIVPKkIGjYf0BTNADpXnZrm1EynJjk1VSZyKroPRFNXQI3eIRAznJillQOffQIADFsFYEgyeJldRkwM1rclbwB5Wc5Lc16yQGEDwAkfEBimDVDYI4DCnxtsXkSFWS@l6R123n1Wuh4NJ7O7/gqyNUtdqAgYThck4hOi6osUKXrwiiugGqVz1suwZY2mvz9ZCP8hZTolAkHle6ES@y8mVRAlbUeHQ0DwGXZG/o3IVbgJ59vD8dXV6/B1h/3xKV89b9vzy/Dx6RJ@Pj6dwmk/P325nMPDMVzu9/Di3ePd/iKc99vLw@Pxz9/H091@CvFDuHkLadeHcDjeceMY4vvf/95fw@nb4XS47Hfh88/w/f7hsp@/HW53e/4F) is a scoring program for \$M\$.

## Other rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Input is pretty flexible. You can specify any two distinct values for M/F: `'M'/'F'`,`0/1`. If you really wanted, you could even take a single integer, with the sign representing M/F, but note that `0` is an input for both. Or the real and imaginary parts of a complex number.

  - You don't have to take any input if you don't want, which should allow you to post answers that just always return 4 or whatever.
- In case there was any confusion, the output *cannot* be random.
- Please include a means of verifying your score.
- Builtins that have this exact mortality table are not banned, but do please implement your own solution as well.
- Explanations are encouraged.

## Additional Bonuses:

Since R is the [language of the month for September 2020](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/language-of-the-month-for-september-2020-r?cb=1), I will be awarding a 500 rep bounty to the R answer with the best score at the end of the month.

Comment: This challenge is depressing. Excuse me while I go write my will...

Comment: I really like the approximation part of this question that throws kolmogorov complexity out the window.

Comment: [Vaguely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/177021/58563) (in the spirit). Pro tip: include a mention that the lowest score wins in bold! :-p

Comment: @Arnauld that challenge was my inspiration for swapping it from kolmogorov-complexity! Added the note about the score, definitely missed that :-)

Comment: @user if R hadn't been the LoTM for September, I would have saved it for Halloween.

Comment: Is there a Depressing Golfing Week here like in C&H?

Comment: Nitpick: It should be "real and imaginary parts of a complex number".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman fixed. Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a problem either in the first chapter or in the numbers: you say the table shows `the probability that a person aged A years will die in the next year`  and I see that at age A=0 that probability is >70(%?), and goes to <1(%?) when reaching age A=113 ? ... this seems reversed. Did you mean "survive"? (and even then, it seems quite low for the low-to-middle ages...)

Comment: @OlivierDulac the output is the life expectancy rather than the probabilities. The two are often presented together in a life table, but I thought life expectancy was more interesting than probability. I guess this is why long-winded preambles are generally frowned upon. I cleaned it up a bit, is that clearer?

Comment: Misleading title. Why isn't the challenge predicting when I, personally, will die, and then scoring me by my accuracy? :-P

Comment: Sex? Gender. (15 chars)

Comment: I think you made the input format too flexible. Especially considering the solution that encoded the inputs as in base 1000 the tables for male and female.

Comment: @TimPederick your final score will be calculated based on your death date.

Comment: Mathematica can do `MortalityData[<|"Age" -> Quantity[60, "Years"], "Gender" -> "Male"|>, "RemainingLifeExpectancy"]`.

Comment: When you say "You can specify any two distinct values for M/F", what are the restrictions on "value"? Can a value be an ordered triple of numbers? Can it be a function? Can it be the lists that give the values of the mortality table?

Comment: @thedefault. that's perfectly fine. Would be interested in seeing another approach like we have here.

Comment: @GregMartin well, yes, encoding the whole table in the M/F values has [been done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210781/67312), and I'm rather regretful of that permissivity, but I stand by my original rules. Do what you want, but it's rather against the spirit of the challenge to encode *that* much information.

Comment: @null I'm using the terminology that the [SSA does](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/NOTES/as120/LifeTables_Body.html), you can take it up with them and I'll change it when they do.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), Score:  <s>59.51</s>  59.10

**L = 52 bytes, M ≈ 0.1150638**

Expects `(n)(m)`, where **m** is **1** for Male or **0** for Female.

```javascript
n=>m=>81-5*m-(.9+m/51+(70-27*m-(.92-m/7)*n)/2e4*n)*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZRNbxs5DIbv/hVzCOAZu2ZE6rupu6fm1lOPbYEWiZPNIhkXrhEsEOS3p@TLdrdBu9iD9XokkiIpPfrr8/3nrxeHmy/Hzby/3D1dbZ/m7eu77evGm7y624zU13enmddjDRupPiObu9M6rebpVHZJZTU/vR22w/uaqdcXg0rKKolSU4lkH0JZVJhyVAmU04uhdMq6VhrlolIpq3cpLpmyepdEuatEMguhwipMRYOUQEUncyc1z42qRsyVqprnQk0DZ81H7XOi3iDB7COxWQqJJpSZopkEiuqXOlJOnlCqVDRKKgidMjXdNWkwgQT1SxpMRyE2byYxb42lGUWNZeKxoseKGsskI7@osVwssaixzEEQJTIlDR29U9Kp6Jo0arq5VBSkYpVIoWiT2fosybohkTpGtgWhaGaMhkpAGSpBv7hTVC9uVNSSK7UOYVsrKIAzVZdgktAojlQZEsxdSDdgploglhUHnHSnnmy0jnjyDeVV2FYSO1acmVah9hkZZBxDRooJOyVESNgueg9hE0mijXYYQg1jsWopWQcoFhsFM2gGLNnaw2RFWrvYLpe2ByvJGoGOMbJjbwZhMehmgXrBaENLNtaGUWwsWCz88WyxODcqmjs0v2K1Y4faKBkI1VHRVhcHpzo4FeCAHy/FyHFwnBt2bsS5ic5Ncm6yc1PBDfD5D3BKd3LEyckgx4pRcuysFBlwFP1UhHoEMka5SnBy7PIqOQxwOAMcATeSwY1jY0ehvCQHxipM/hooMJakAmNpKTA1ApgGXloDL9ZClZDAC0fwgrMXXBzjJTkv2Xlpzgs7LwkSOnjBfcg4DwXG@FRWqrPSMdpdF78AioqdkaJSHJVWIMChWnHsrTdSupOSnRQBItZ6RcSeDRXLWRmx01FGMBlIukFiKXfk6CfrmPsVKXgqHMninUeMTFwACVCxO6XdsYcDlUd0I@KNi149CkSLxR8E3Ed/dMQflO@MNOcDDKB0rxJ9/ocQjIzV4FiABXt3/4@Oq/1h3B0Oysisv3Cm8ko7ZH/W62l4WAzDfdCVq3GeRp7O7Jt/fAd8X9q6Gm2Gt@/nj5gxCzXbDOffZ2yL9dZMV6tBhrWZ2D9bu9jPX/e3O7rdX4@fTh7mxw/Hk4f7QMf9@c3fu8tRpsdhPHkY1fnVEIY/huVyeDks18vJ4jyzm@DKv7ry71yf2U2fpsXj4udclh/mN4fD/qAOam0VnOpNtZqfWb272B92bjOOrOOVhn13PNzM1@NEt7v5@vjnNKwGrP0bZfpp8@ns6Rs)

or [Get the raw data](https://tio.run/##Tci7DoIwFAbgnac4my21hTYSNFhGNp6AMBAEhdBTAupifPZaooPLf/nG5tms7TLMd4720rleO9S50flR8iQ0nIgTM1EiGUljrtKvKG6ilIZII9UdfIXoStBQ1VlQ/Dro7ULQnzgDhDNItQ3GKLwCgFLMj/VGeoKUSEozT8UfxRu9g9biaqdOTPZKKiFEuQefRS1GOyDZwY5S9wE) in the format expected by the [scoring program](https://tio.run/##dZjJjiS5EUTv9RV1nAZ6CNIXLpC@RYAw0FE6SJf5@9YzZ24HKRuTrGREMJzmZubO@fevP7//@vv3H7@tbGf9/GaIZIgWm8GbflhLYxgtnaG3jJ/f87Tk2twt58/vr7la8vicd8iWPD6j5WHwxi3T2hwMo01Wmb1NJvM0bv/K3RZr5mqL@3O2zdJJRDyQ0c6uoesBb0N3WjNCytF86PnenAfjVNRxY4rVJsvErLUj2@a9wWpWQ@fBYDUeD2tDj49mepzFCMpZTMNdzO9izmIasiJ0FmP48hubs5qesFrGRwsW9wuXnTa5ZrttXm@r9sSgzXzZbK7ZFNoWgsS8nfoeumDNtcYoVK3XThg6v8ZprhjGbpNbx2r71DB0cdYeRrZ1h64hCqzhbY0aej1vjVeM0dasQYGNXhk/7YS@hcqNf9cOV927mhUBKnVshAeyYshKRlaUUe@KWiLqhX6BrHu8mQvGyom1Xd9TO24hFJpPfVvNFCB15xBEo2mfxaIhmoFRXQqBUbCNCnBcQFpd7LyutzPrW19baehtbf1Ypu9ZV0XZfW/dl2Tr1Nprt5Aa1tULQAsFyWdd@ayST6nobkP6ufK56hlXPawl8QgAqSeuevKqZ5V6SkT/Rz5TSO@K@Uv6ydKPNoJ@lCuEU2rymxRrx0s4UjuDgEQ@4u8X@hkln5ElHyv1WJZ6rniUCVQjZqMabTKuLaAahfmFbBQZsllestmlmr1LNcKRoUeJZ3iJRslHNF4cIHNxVZNXNfuqZlzVRA1drJiXEFlZQTXlQyhmXcWc@hbh7TIAwShVCEZKRi971lCaWNrf17gJkF7O1UtevVgJRQlAJzIQBoWNUJQjhKLJL0Y7koqiPhXmzfDV@@XKLNO4ypwX/1rkK9uYJZUSjNgFRLKQ2r0XIl6G5xeB2mPhbOUMX1bUvP5jJeGnUvZVSQmhtn83WmC/ZBIlolGX@xVHCUI2fDXyvyXy4/v37//88fd//fbjL9///Afjn3@zH7/WVDXpa9sefUTvOSWMkRYnx@p7bk9pxMz2yjk8In1LLrbPzIwdeXyHlOPpfa5jSw8uqSiGe8y@o7tPCSpWX@b97O7H7Gorw20M6xF7lMzWWn3a3KfzRpWraUztNQZvm5LeXLm35bbp3lMqXASYo1va6H1LkGvywBrbeON2aZMtrhHjTPYbLpnudFv3EUKckuw@SbA@54m5ttR7fJqN3U@aEyFCPgS4fG52azY10wcQ2jAHNztTVbLnXr3b7rU3Cb6fc2IY/401Q9onGjbmfevJlA2MHfrMODu5W5YA8mNZgeHdqqwuZxdPSG6FPYs3E8HeaTKLCs997ZGDGFV2x3bAPzZy7ikLIRunn@hzTANY3IRsPF8ELHKW3D57FzG6GRDhMjPCxtkAnH3JcEg3dxADaC6X96wFeyLWHKfHkg2JJyvj9MI/ZUnHiHBmD@tjbrkTAPnpc46ud6Sm@rZgm2QnRqQqPuziN/td@5wRsjGbYhFgVt7kaBX0yBVGOo7cLWDR2OKNpx05XLJ9W9pX9H1kdnPHnmPlqffJ9zbh5w2QuKY88JAv32KVnUGQTAnpmDmysFRbYQAI7uLHPkNe6bFzHpC3FTlkmwlrQPBJElnohGqbFMJT25nyUegRyv9ZYA6RZa3C7TzkSeKwWXD2tR76XOW4qGOhpV70KvPlZmgD9wdECHUui80sX2ff5GmKUKafk1nSkT/DGaJxWA8wcmry@tgZmUSiJrMB8bgSzSMDR@MB2opwgY6myKREdTMAl4bkD@KBlXhuBa7eSCRG1l50zuqTUAxec1KRWrVMhrbzIVN0qnIQgJQPneIK1UrhEefM6RuvUpUglZEP/yFd1WGB0RmIrXa4NAXTDkRQBnuiuaHuWuSS1zmOsVRVWCHmfGq1ppyAx35KyFV0VmCc6xJ6rdAUyELmfjMBz6hFdsoXLUgspqy6RFCr7OTgNqpRIgdkHlJeGDM9cx9/qBXXQ78TF7enWgczHUOGABI4cVLM4AheIwdaWBQeTEWzZVepkB8/IZtcjkrcJiZmxPlhpbg8JJiuukOmeGoVY6Bbwsv8KVUygJ1BiQeK2M/@LsZRXaQBJCwS0KgQ7TxyLgkIipMAJ8wsLu/BoI7ToYjvvUTNhcrIibizHnJVIVBVGtr7Q6@m2spuMQfoxYaoObh@H1vWaLKjDtrq2cG/F0sCDEL19nLy2gpbVfE1Fu7XmZ2sVgkmIf0p2K1CDE74wtUr2lJVhqmslLMqFjHAioGmbgqQw9CDk9wjkEdB1U26RuqE5kxYp6kk3/aoqL0fTcFb/PgKFt5qKuaTz9DINaPiLSAmpYwF9T4rsVxHcgBl6gD3ftRVYlGg4hvcP1Lf1m5O13sehXUUMNwLG56SnYKPGKevh2THBdSBeKaJM1kYawflq/qgjm/qKy18p7PA1ujilShKw5LFH5GeXh7HOxHVzhNE1nEYd/LqXOAMLK1DsTzM1KlQYrpXh4L/qi0hKxBe/QgABbSkDykoTP0H2FIR1HdsrCXVb0gEAESfQcFBRv1@hvqMA6uWqb/AeFCf@gpsXr3EIbw@q4eQMVU3QatB1LdnOEeNARp11RF1CGFiWqqpdeR/Hp95j9ZgaeoIcA5XbwC5NUE72CdOq7JPI4EHqdzTWyCEOimgbTq00HkzVHrpyun2VhVzvFINHVXcVlUhqjdSkgZCR9pQpUYYm@JHOUYOnZZDB2/xxOrsTdQqGfeTdQ7vKt9UXZowyKtqSzuAnlRlITz/Hhj2KrNwCrnzV1VToo1HFUWFHyiojKJseED5DEeX/r5oskh4rgq5MF/Pd0hUSLaOmegvEocpPS9uFUuVPPePKc4TEIpyKKeEK5RBNUtwhfqH4uHwx@pkgHJIG/H4mEqiB92Uyh66wQHegepYQwk8r42te8TBLqxOOYHoPjY21AFXicPK6TD0F91u9P1@3xD1yfwL1lQd2wi7f2SGKeQv48I8F/V7ftzOvtSerY/bybyLiM@pUwWNfvi8tjqqoOXrvTXFnjcyzPdzEJ8Dg70Wd8oXb1v9Y@0l3dRZQs0aSnjjw3kMu17zTRrUDzb@WlDHNBgxPtajU6XurI@skOj9gkMLZx3lqAGqX44DxGvB0P8EUczjPcPxcsvXPiJDLRLLa0Zkbyp2@abf0gkwEcI6H6RBQbD@BdxURTOV8ufyIpsOhLR2kR9PyjfVw78Adx0SXV3aKwVbFrzpN167V78lnmNJH0nHVXSUec2Uwavpfa1Or6qTs85JLyCrqG1V@7dkmHnnRyna9yb8/jm1/S4195sH94US2SvQqLDou/yNPKFThd6hUyuGfMpewqLWCgbE@vLnrl6Rupp0Ie9A69i3XwKjK//1678).

#### Method

This is based on two cubic regressions, with a trade-off between code size and accuracy.

For women, this computes:

$$f_0(x)=81-\frac{9}{10}x-\frac{7}{2000}x^2+\frac{23}{500000}x^3$$

And for men:

$$f_1(x)=76-\frac{469}{510}x-\frac{43}{20000}x^2+\frac{17}{437500}x^3$$

#### How accurate is it?

Below is a graph of the errors produced by the function according to the age and the sex.

[image: errors]

Answer (score 12):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), score=<s>67.47</s> 47.92

30 bytes, MSE = 0.54587

-1 byte (and -1.47 in score) thanks to Dominic van Essen.

```r
pnorm(scan(),31,41,F)*scan()-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZVNjhw3DIX3OoXgbLqcGqKofxnwNqcIDDR62s4AcbXd3QPP7cePj7aTRbIRq0oSi3zkJ11fX7/sl@vnw@103A/LmnUtuv6xvPX3h/SaawxhjhB@i0/7l@d7/Ijlx3t8usXjp/Ma9/O3v592PNzOL2s876fL4/kxzmHr4ufzHo/7Y9St8f3bBV9CuF@f73/F9/F06FVmXyNMqTBFyoDJYi9JaoJRqRlmk1rW2KZUzLUhta0xtC4V21tzU6VieytSJ0wWLGlJmsKoNHhpmzR8rFOwPNQhHT5rl471tcmA64qIsKEWmYNmsw1Z1FYmSQipqkAn7N8kY2OZjLp4TKVLg5vS6LtUGfhvgbdEs2FjgTdsL0nUtqsk2w5nCCrDmRl3lt1ZhjMzlRFmOIMJ2WPL8GY7Et1kFRQwZpcrTWmYS0MGfp86c4KxZEJqku1rNbVTMUlSlslRbSJJNh9KVdPGTGA2vOmUbDHokIal2mVMGrXJxhy0SnezmSkUS7N0pdm4Pwl@oSq90VhgurHiU2ax0VTx@Acz7FzbJbEBWDokgg2VMVQWozLKwn8Vuij8YXYhuSZLyiYja5JkcGyWsRRTQXKzMfELBeFKNYlULE92kVqbQSNOFRODsikDVBdEOLnhd5vMxtGGYWXYpA976cnGxllr2eFLhzdZn/TdhxSjoTsvENpUMHy649OJDynyNIwfx8fpUacHvgweE8DoKU5PdXo66SFE/4NPM6UHYw7GTyU/lgj4sVoBHNKUvShJZiY4RjuMCQl8rH8D@FHio5X4JNKTKulxeKwSoMY6G9RYksWPBVBjYQZgY5EBm56JzSA1Y5Aa0xFmK4RHM6Gx4gOazB5A5YpTU52a4dSoU1NoNuuK5g1RWRVQw3MIxHQnZnK0hk/eAQDGSgVgjGTwMhoNmeiWX1AvgPEynZfqvCSCYgUAJ3aAwFjYAMVqBFDsY4BN01CxqCfD9Ao7794rjYeGk9lcfzoJVbQRFQJj3QWJ7Ahh9pmKZB542RVgjtQ58WQIia3p508iwj9JGU4JQWD6nijF/oVJIUTK6c3hIBB2DDsj/43IEsL5/ohr5OPzfro/XfbDy3pb/Dp7@ddN9pCw8HrF9fMeFxKutYPfPw@4f@DgsL1TO4fnWHB//fOOO2tZlg9pCbfT5XrG5kPefo@6xLfx4P7sLZyO98Mb8xtvX5@PV1x@nHz3ZvWHHyv@3OnGPvNhef0O)

The input format is: age as an integer, then a newline, then sex, then a newline. Sex is encoded as 98 for men and 106 for women.

Approximates the actuarial tables by the survival function of a normal distribution (the survival function is 1 - the cumulative distributions function). I tried a few families of distribution, and the normal minimized the MSE.

Let \$\phi(x;\mu,\sigma)\$ be the density of a \$\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)\$ distribution. The approximation used is

\$f(x)=a+m\int_x^\infty\phi(t;\mu,\sigma)\,dt\$

I tried using different parameter values for men and women, but the best score is obtained by using the same values of \$a\$, \$\mu\$ and \$\sigma\$, and picking only different values for \$m\$. Since \$m=98\$ for men and \$m=106\$ for women are the optimal values, I use those to encode the sex directly.

(Actually, the optimal values would be \$m=98.25528\$ for men and \$m=106.34315\$ for women, but using such values to define the sexes really feels like cheating. It would lead to a score of 47.49, a slight improvement.)

Plot of the approximation for men:

[image]

Plot of the approximation for women:

[image]

Comment: I think you can lose 1 byte by using ```0``` and ```1``` for men and women: ```function(x,s)pnorm(x,30+s*2,41,F)*5*(20+s)-2```

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice, thanks!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Using `15` and `16` is even better, actually (see new version).

Comment: Re: double-```scan()``` input.  We were just discussing this a couple of days ago in the new [R chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55468258#55468258).  Obviously there isn't any consensus yet, but I think one needs to be careful before automatically assuming that the required extra intervening newline is allowable...

Comment: (I realize that I'm hardly in a position to criticize, though, bearing in mind my own horrible rule-abusing answer...)

Comment: This is @Giuseppe ‘s call, obviously. In general, I don’t think it should be an issue. Different languages require different separators when reading input: commas, whitespace, newlines, etc. Here, the separator I am using is `\n\n`. If that isn’t acceptable to Giuseppe, I’m happy to revert to the previous version with +3 bytes.

Comment: I think you're probably right (especially here, where the input is especially flexible).  I just thought it was sufficiently ambiguous to be worth mentioning, and especially in case there are any potential new R-golfers that might be studying our answers...

Comment: looks OK to me. Perfectly reasonable input format, especially considering the extreme permissivity I've allowed to date, haha

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), Score 151.8,

## 32 bytes, 3.6 MSE

```
#-Cos[x(Pi-.02)/238]~Sum~{x,#2}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nXOb84ukIjIFNXz8BIU9/I2CK2Lrg0t666QkfZqFbtf0BRZl5JtJKju6sCDPg6@iA4CODmCpJQiuWCaKlW1lFSUFDSSY82N9NRjoVzLIGc2lg1fYegxLz01GgDHUNDy9j//wE)

I noticed that the differences of the values were similar to `Cos(x) [0,pi/2]`
So, accumulated Cos(x) works pretty good on men...

***MALE***
**MSE 0,90**
[image]

***FEMALE***
**MSE 6,29**
(*I guess Cos(x) understands men better...*)

[image]

Special thanks to @att for golfing my code down to 33 bytes

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1nXOb84ukIjIFPXQM/ASFPfyNgiti64NLeuukJH2ahW7X9AUWZeSbSSo7urAgz4OvogOAjg5gqSUIrlgmipVtZRUlBQ0kmPNjfTUY6FcyyBnNpYNX2HoMS89NRoAx1DQ8vY//8B), same output, using `76` for male and `79` for female

Comment: @att Great! well done!

Comment: @att now there's a clever use of the flexible input! Very nice.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), score <sup><s>56.12...43.94</s></sup> 43.92

\$L=35\$, \$M\approx0.220060\$

```
->x,f{f.*1.87e6-(21676+(66-x)*x)*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZVdaxtZDIbv/SuGbAu2E2vn6HxDs/cLLfsDjCneeEwNu7VxEnA3yW/PvnqV9q6FIGXmSBp9Pcfnx7@/ve5uX1d/XG72T3tZBml1Kqu5hlLL9byU1WWxtL@X1932YTvcDuuapdebASplqCSpQUWxB5WsUEFyhBolp5uhdMk4K01ygaqS4V2KqywZ3iVJ7lBRzEKlBKggBUHKKAUvcxeY5yYVEXOVCvNcpCFwRj6wz0l6oxrNPkowSxVFQjlINJNRIvxSZ8rJE0pVCqKkwtApS8NXE4Ip1Qi/hGCQKsG8g6h5IxYyiohlymNFjxURy1RmfhGxXFliEbHMQRklBkkIHb1T2qXgTJs0fFwrC4KySrRItJfZ@qzJuqFROmWwA5VoZoEN1ZFlQI14Cl0ivEKTAstQpXWqYGeFBYQs1dVoKrFRIUoNVKO5q@ADIUgtVJZVGDnpLj2ZtI548o3lVdpWURsrZ4YqYJ@ZQeYYMlNM/FJihMTPRe8hbaJoNGnDUGmUxaqVZB2QWEwq37AZtAzWHiy0CSvKlgvt4UmyRrBjgdkFb4bwcMTHRumF0kRLJmujVJOFh7anzS2b71btDF2bJCOgOiPocXFiqhNTSQzB8RoMGSfGgQkOjDow0YFJDkx2YCqBITc/IaZ0R0YdmUxkrAogY0MCKwQo@jhUeiQrhjfU6MjY1gKZQGJCJjFKYDQTGOfFZgBQkpNiFSa/BkCKJQlSLC2QUiNJaQSlNYJiLYQaE0EJkaBw6MqNMVCSg5IdlOagBAclUY2doHARMucBUgxMQFIdkk5pS64@eTBiMwIjxRlphYocVCsueOsNke6IZEdEyYa1HmzYfQFlOQMOmw7g4MtRtBsdlnJnjj5Z59tXpPCOcBaLd54xsoRCOsiI7RS6YzcGK4/sRuTlFr16FsgWq98E3Ee/bdRvkjc4moPB5WfpXiX7/AMNysDT0XkgBHbh/gqLzWy2PZ3Ox4v9YGxmayCtdVplIl4U/21k2t59eRqe98/weDw9HOch9AVeXJ6HN98PH4bd@nIz7DfDy/Aym87n4xkBsZIz@zFihM@Hr7vpArfD8@AG17fD3AOsD5uVGUIvlkv9EeL324H@94f/ptnsI0L@@Zecp@3un8PX6X7@blysw0buvhz/PbnNJ5jQdXZ/dzxPeJqH64@LJeSnxez0@HA/XH3P7rcn/vdy9fb@u8d70f3Vez69/g8)

Input is an age \$x\$ and a float \$f\$, which is `4.027e-5` for male and `4.362e-5` for female. (See below for an alternative version that takes \$f\$ as an integer instead.) The approach is to fit a cubic polynomial to the life expectancy averaged across both sexes, then scale this polynomial by a *sex factor* to recover sex-specific approximations. The polynomial selected for the average life expectancy is
$$
\frac{x^3-66x^2-21676x+1870000}{23840}
$$
and the sex factor is
$$
\begin{cases}0.96,\;\text{male}\\1.04,\;\text{female}.\end{cases}
$$
In other words, the life expectancy of a male is approximately \$0.96\$ times that of an average human (male or female). Similarly, the life expectancy of a female is approximately \$1.04\$ times that of an average human.

The plot below shows the squared error as a function of age for each sex. The dashed grey line represents the mean squared error for both sexes.

[image]

One point of interest in the code is the explicit call to the `*` method of the float `f`. Everything to the right of `f.*` is interpreted as the method argument, so the polynomial [doesn't need to be enclosed in parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101857/92901).

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), score 50.06

\$L=40\$, \$M\approx0.220981\$

```ruby
->x,f{f/9e3*(56541-(656+(2-x/33r)*x)*x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZXdahtJEIXv5ykGZwOSbJen@r8h3vuFhDyAEIvWkoggGwnZBiW2n905dcrJ3S6YOp7p6pr66a91evzn@@vm9vX6z/PV7ml307dxMcslJ72elVwuZ@H6fBPjab4429/L62b9sB5vx2XN0uvVCEkZkiQ1SBR7CJIDRCVHyCQ5XY2lS8ZaaZILpErG7lJcsmTsLklyh0QxjyBFISoFQcokBS9zF7jnJhURc5UK91ykIXBGPvDPSXqjTOYfRc0zSEBCWSWayyQR@1JnyskTSlUKoqTC0ClLw1cTggXKhH0JwWCDqO1WCbYbsZBRRCwTjxU9VkQsk8z8ImK5WGIRsWxDYJSokhA6eqdCl4K10KTh46GyIIhVEopEe5mtzyFZN0KUTqu2ECSam7KhYWIZkAlP2iVilzYp8NQqrVPU1goL0CzVZTJJbJRGqUqZbHsQfEBVaqFYVjpx0l16Mmsd8eQby6v0rRJsrJwZqoB/ZgaZY8hMMfFLiRESPxe9h/SJEqJZG0aQRlusWknWAYnFbOAbNoOeau1RsSKtXWqHC@3hSrJGsGPK7NSbIVyc8LFJeqE105LZ2miD2cJFO6fNPZufrdoZujZJRkB1RtDj4sRUJ6aSGILjNRgyTowDow5McGCiA5McmOzAVAJDbv6DmNIdmeDIZCJjVQAZGxJYIUDRxxGkR7JieEMmR8ZOLZBREqOZxAQCEzKBcV5sBgAlOSlWYfJrAKRYkiDF0gIpNZKURlBaIyjWQsiUCIpGgsKhB54YAyU5KNlBaQ6KOiiJMnWCwoOQOQ@QYmACkuqQdFo75MEnD0ZsRmCkOCOtUMhBteLUW2@IdEckOyKBbFjrwYbdFxDLGXDYdAAHX04SutFhKXfm6JN1vv2IFN4RzmLxzjNGFi2kg4zYmUJ37MZg5ZHdiLzcolfPAtni4DcBz6PfNsFvkjc4moPBw8/SvUr2@TcatMrVyXkgBHbh/h8Wq2FYH4@nw9l@MFbDUtmqlWzXd1@exufdM7wejw@HmWqf48X5eXzz//Bh3CzPV@NuNb6ML8P2dDqcEATHcLAfIEb4e/9tsz1j2/55dIfL23HmAZb71bU5QueLRfgd4uZ25P77/Y/tMHxEyL8@y2m73nzdf9vez/6Y5ktdyd2Xw79H9/kEF24d7u8Opy2eZnr5cb6A/TQfjo8P9@PFr@zePfG/l4u39792vJewu3jPp9ef)

Despite being within the rules, taking \$f\$ as a float (as above) feels more than a little 'cheaty'. This version uses the same general approach, but here \$f\$ is an integer: \$12\$ for male and \$13\$ for female. The polynomial used for the average life expectancy is
$$
\frac{x^3/33-2x^2-656x+56541}{720}.
$$

Comment: what does the `r` do in `33r` ?

Comment: @Razetime `33r` is a rational number literal. With just `x/33` on its own you get floor division, which isn't wanted here. The main reason to use `33r` is that it's one byte shorter than the float `33.0`.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), score <sup>53.76</sup> 52.78

`L = 46`, `M = 0.122983`

Takes M/F as 1/0 on the right side and age on the left side. A simple third degree polynomial approximation. The J polynomials read from left to right, so `81 - 0.9x - 347e-5x² + 455e-7x³` for the 1 case. The 0 case just modifies the numbers a little bit to `76 - 0.92x - 207e-5x² + 385e-7x³`. `p.` evaluates the polynomial at `x`, in this case the age.

```
p.~81 _0.9 _347e_5 455e_7-5 0.02 _14e_4 7e_6&*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZTLbptHDIX3fgrCRmzLF2bIuaspULRAV0UX2aatYLi/nRSubUgO0EXhV3fOoZVdstCRNBfOIfnN/PNyqCc38uNaTuRCdvhOws@lyi/vf/v15VGfh8km6ZRNLn3ZVCm1Lpt@WSVpctlYWTZFMNOOz15WB7//rIJNvcUmzHuKXXlw1/m3dh08XW1vlyea6FVnp5YqvWgZ0rPip2t16aY1S09ai7SptUobWpu0rrVLa6FV65BWtE5pWTHp2kyaacvSkrYmdWqXOrQXqV37lNp0VKk42qQWnYOasDCrYY2ru1TTjNmkeUqZNFbi7NK1oSSN0UrVkaUUpg1NJgURpLgaNpk6NiFAl4wA0AiQI0BGAGilkYwAobCQEQArnXuzaTHJkb5PbV186HDxTstQmPWmGSMognhBmp7ROIhh0DVjgbE@nugUmobY1FzFhjYX6zom1TDeaNKq9tAELczesnajJuxyLWKm6DYU51tii6bOAkGmYXDQfeeiro6OsObwmaXytMpiVjopDFy4rTB4jpJwNqtnCArqOigNiWhBZpobxPmXKXKJIWNT@Ef66Do@lYMF2bEARgsWCSrHUwaRs1HwGQXSB8UlaEnEZ8SSEd3vk7H60AIWe4CKSrWAtge0ndAS3fBIagPaYNaCWQ9mczBbgtkazHYyS3K/BW2bQa0HtZXUwiioRYXBKwnOUU/XmckrLhI0BbVACdQaobVKaJ3MOi@zBrKoI2AtQSsSKHHVQCvMgFYYAK09k9ZBWMcgrKgJNBXCapmwsk/O1hLWErDWgHUErBawFmqahJWdq6wqaMVlAKk9SJ0UIOfRLoCKMgPUFqCORiWQHeYtakhOZ3Bag1MnoaghCMVthMIZEEWFLZ4lqE8JY5NeoilxkaKljVcwLkCLCnJjVWtklKCi90gZt5E5ZSaZ@T7kSIvuWSyPq0Za4v56XNBXREfwSRCZUiTAen0llGKcSAEmecTb9D08D7YPn@//5vP5YX1qKb15fqfnqPy7tR3/v8LA2Z8vy/XHBzlZ/rv69/FuWZ9cHK7RLjm9@OFmJXawn91uH7ZrkZiNP4y5f5xPj@TNMw44fyt/Hfvqp/WlbJfd57t4ti8E7uTm@TC9lU@4iWkf8W65v336uH6NeLTbj@6uH7bL13NevZ/a@dFuJWf8ESev9ms3lyeye9p@ur/dLo93V9fLoQl2bSzJhz/2Dr4A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score 94.40, 58 bytes, 0.60 MSE

Just simple linear approximations. `True` for *female* and `False` for *male*.

```python
lambda a,g:[75+5*g-(.89+g/30)*a,12-a/11][a>81]+(70<a<90)*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXLbhtHELzzK@ZiaJeiWvN@CE6AIJBPMQIkuQk6rM0lI0CihCUVwF@vVNcwCQzYyGVqd6anp7umavfly@nP50N4@/y8nc0P5uLi4u1xevq0ncy02d/clXSZ1vurQWq73F8HO66njfNX07Vz93fTj9XdXw7Fvp/eNyz5N2yX42l5eBnG1WqHfPNf0@OgufH@4fbjT7/cYvKuWml5YwChbUxpEj2gSgyAIjEBskSElCSxAGKHILECvETd50QDrY65SXKAKgmpcpGEVDlLioAkSUOiJOTIQRI2Zy9ZNzjJGmkl47TUJGMtVSnIkooU7EtZCg5NSapORqk6GcAIwEvD9uSkFYJFzmTFIllsgpdYxSE@FsHmmMXrSxJsilGChqEnjfPsMDpWHi2LDI1lBdSDyVAEdYQsVSGRQoBFiyGK04ggXsFLUHASdc2yfY9c2OerVBzni7RIsDjHoy59S7wPD6KQ2gey4NEiR4vyvBOvS5Z35JBSASkzQUNc0eZcp94lKY1gNRAdI6MLpN4hsSdozc7xdpztk1Y89vWSG2vsN4uyVQA8PkvjqLzlzjxzJHHKK28tUlNgB6uBnQeyESTwmd2zQVLsJSlH1CPq4rNTZpjekXknRbvtrfcuybOTwNFzdFxVHViWjNHpWKOOhTNKbxceRne/Wv3jD6he9aTiT138leJP1D556DpR8ceu/tTVn7v6S1d/6eqvXf2N6s/fF3/p2o9d@43ap9oTq4f2tRWA9gULKDWwgPfUfujaVwlB@1py7AVB/EoW1K@pof7a5a83DVBq4YJuAtdoAqUeJgiFJtAbDj1X6LngAvUm5K/1Qf6tgxYGF7hCF2gWdYHrLojdBaW7wHcXVAIvOVOecEGiCQo90Di67gS9YXiAIrFsA2ArrRC6FbKnB/TrAHCVXtAG1AsdaJNIouCF4gg0CJRHK1BhjlXBCnrTjX5tZKQXX9leYWyhLTPvLNP8qX@feA2JJUaeFJkh8rjQOWTM@cvBy/D9EyGZyo90h36qfP9KdDLOjmi0BV1BU9ATXFEP/esJzpMM4aINtES3x//6YjvvzGla9vNpmPbzxuznw3ZexpuVMQ@785u@GLPMp9flYPqv5g7B95ieH4/zV8v/LTL10zwdhkemOwccX58wYa7N46wrq9XTUf@Oy/PrYTsw/A7Bw@6rcszVt4oc12uP2N3zYjBtHg5mmQ77eXDejuf5HqlLwx/LK7Z@mFDxuLofwfO4@vTlNB9xutZy/pUePz8vWtDgLrk6mrU@P@mu1cvycDgNF7///Otvtzc6/U78blzrw3bEJn29MO/MgPCN4f6NYcZxfPsb)

Visual representation of the approximation:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), score 46.00036

*Pushing the limits of 'any two distinct values' as input more than somewhat...*

45 bytes, mean-squared-error 7.9e-6

```r
function(a,s)s%/%gmp::as.bigz(1e4)^a%%1e4/100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZXfblw3Dsbv/RSDFFnMtI7K/5IC@NZ3foUGE@c4O4Bjez0OtunLpx@pIIsU6GKxNo44cyRRJD/@NM9f709327vt96ft9uX4cPvl6uvd54fbl9Pjw/54eT6cX//6@uOnp7dvj@f2/vTxjz1vdvjt@Po17K9M9PWn3Xn7fXc6787wcLo7bR9277/sXv657e4e7@8f/316@LjDxnZ6eNk@bs/ntxc3Vz84fBVwE0HUBc8gGkY0CU8QkxJjmnkQC76rEZsQOxNjC3c82MJYj90kLCRiJBokNkkCn0d5IRUltUHanYzwaCfrjE@DHO99TApVij4RSlDvQUM6jSE04W9Ow2JlZmPuwTiGlZy1441OdursvXPAaefBfUweITzVpZIbKuxDRE2UYRCedRJ3hKkiHYn1OQTnyYwO16Y4CjNDlTsyD7Xp6sM1umsP1@Gh07qRhrEMw2nYRJZVsinmQy26GdYa1trESDoRNLuIIBtz@HWbwx0pBEzv00c3n50CugSHhtRIgbfhPiI8EEJgecTEFsSK5LWLS1cUwmx0N@9w8upwcf2/CI53EyLjTJSTVnUrDYiNJxxiY26Mb0JDWIgjaAZxvEO9BE2g6BxUixRVVQgPqVANhdAQGB2TsWZbQSRC5IgUD84d0Gjmf2CTIJgpDDVTJhZ81kiRoR@8eJ8IxyBJ9h6kHsEzEIg5@i9EkBhiEZQDCgSqPPEW4sJpnwaB4TIGBM76w6viL9uCVbMtUWONMRRC6OjoExxGju5zdA7ExkLsghZIC94NZbSBIs3sZYjJicfsLug8HTOVh2bi0QfExUfINGP@KC7eIFaIm4Nlf0FcQYmAWHU2koKoACjbCeICDwiM@vUBkjItNNag6RD84qfd7fH@9vP98WXb/WP34XR@uj9@2d3g8/Xu@1Vz2s4XuezdzdX5@PR0/2VPb5nn5X/unwNa5sPj5/f32/4vt1TeTVc3h8Nhebj@Pz1cf/dw883Rj7F/2o4Pb87/@nx83j682Z6fH58vnrc7BHy7795mv9zBmMNYswGjLb9Ic4Hh5gpDze1yF7M55mI0D5jeHLsjlvHm2B3WfMJoyxXSgmG4BZwEtcBLnw3LfbQOj95bx3KPNuDYEQ/Wu7U5ylCu18a5UpogIOemuYSaYp/NCtlWQNZbwItFuTZvA6canEkZwj6DM4zSOHdzk9wNX4hI4SvN8qXLl8JXGq/4FL6WycAUvnKDlBflZnCtq1IyW2BORhs4XHolBJOZSDTNl551FstqiLZZI@eENM1lXAUVqjRgCN94NsUuHi2wknsbswznXFQC7K0vQ2msCsXaOpeh3C4NBzC3HmUyKqZSerZpOWZFVvCj0uu1tjdJWUszZIH1XhF4yeAVotVJVh6sjtNVw1qjTTTHFEPaqDEy22ZZgaaRo9SbKkat5CwPt0wyy8XZXChPzVgWoirGFR2vYrSaJBxGbUaNOQzLsY8aJceoyeBDYXENLMbaMVaP9VlH9NEsSeiLFdQ6Fjl9kdOLnAJo5ZLoLHIWOLzAkQWOLnBsgeMLnF7gFD9/Q07MhY4sdLzQyWyATooFZgokXbJIm1rMJOYwtNDJ7gU6XOSwFzlS4IgXOIub1ALA2CImM7R1HYCYDBLEZFggpmsRMwqYMQqYLCEMWQHDWsCU@FKdk8DYAsYXMGMBwwsYK0OzgKmG8NIDxCSggKUvWGaN2eyyOgCspEZgJRYrI8oUDz2T41X6RGUuVHyhIsVIlh6M5L0BkzEDklQHkNRLajKTkgx5VoxL2cX5apGou2IxGavy5cMbR1FSrGRPoTp5c1TmWtXQuuR0ZV8JVoll3QjVj@vWkXWjfINkLEAKgkp9ZVl1/o5IjVyztLgoGPLi/e94fDpvV/ljst/f7usX5M361bksbtYX/Bj9JrX0xx@h8@3j83axN/@FDz/vMQ379U8)

Input is an integer `a` as age, and one of two 'big integer' values `s` to specify M/F sex.
Output is a 'big rational' number.

As (presumably) encouraged by the generously-flexible input rules, the sex-specifying values are integral for the calculation (although in this case probably more so than intended...).
Each of M,F big integers are constructed as the 1...120th power of 1e4 multiplied by 100x the life expectancy at each age: essentially, a base-10000-encoding.
The `life_expectancy` function simply decodes the `a`th base-10000 digit and divides by 100.

Even though the function uses the arbitrary-precision `gmp` library for calculations, a small number of the decoded values still contain inaccuracies at the 2nd decimal place, for reasons that I don't understand.
Nevertheless, the mean-squared-error is (as expected) sufficiently close to zero that this doesn't matter, since we need to add 1 to it anyway to get the score.

Comment: @Giuseppe: I hereby renounce the 500rep bounty in case this answer is the shortest in R, and I will try to come-up with a less 'cheaty' one...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this (don't know R) but shouldn't `library(gmp)` be included in the byte count, since it is explicitly referenced in the code? This [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/92901) seems to suggest so, but I'm happy to be corrected. (Very clever approach, by the way!)

Comment: @Dingus: It *shouldn't*, because I've included ```gmp::``` in the code itself, which *should* retrieve the library without explicitly loading it first.  I've tested it (just now) on my own installation of R, and on rdrr.io, and this works fine.  For some reason, this isn't happening on TIO, though, so I needed to add the ```library(gmp)``` line in the header.

Comment: @Dingus: I figured it out.  I forgot to add the ```gmp::``` to the additional code in the footer.  That's fixed now, and I've removed the ```library(gmp)``` altogether.

Comment: The ages range from 0-119 rather than 1-120. It'll probably just require a change of constant but it does mean your score is quite a bit higher

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  Fixed now (I just needed to delete "0000" at the end of each constant, which I'd only added in the first place to save a ```-1``` in the code).

Comment: Ah. Well now that I am actually reading your answer, I'm a little sad about allowing such an encoding scheme. The genie is out of the bottle now! Not to worry, though, this is an `R + gmp` answer rather than an R answer, so I'd disqualify this for the 500 rep bounty anyway. But I'll keep an open mind and certainly consider it for a secondary bounty :-)

Comment: I knew it was 'cheating' in spirit, so I'm happy to be disqualified (as indicated in first comment).  I've submitted a 'proper' answer, too, now, even though it isn't beating Robin (yet...).

Comment: Let's push the limit... a character count 19 and score of 20 for `function(a,s)s[a+1]`, where s is a judiciously chosen vector of length 120. In pure R :D. I won't post it as an answer, this is just to show how this can be (ab)used.

Comment: @JayCe - Ha ha.  Of course that would work.  While I was concocting my 'cheat', though, I was quite careful to comply with the letter of the rules ("two distinct values" or "a single integer"...), anticipating the inevitable downvote(s)...  I concluded that since using a vector wasn't specifically allowed, it would be too risky (as well as less fun/inventive)...

Comment: @Giuseppe - Thanks very much indeed for the bounty!  I'm not sure that I really deserved it, except perhaps for sneakiness, but I'm very grateful and happy anyway.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen this question got way less attention than I had hoped. Take it as an honorable mention prize for your other one too :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), score 75.74445

61 bytes, mean-squared-error 0.222

```r
function(a,s)s*predict(loess(c(82,58,35,14,3,1)~c(0:5*24)),a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZVNj9s2EIbv/hUCAhTSVjvQ8JsBfPXNf6GBopVbAYrtWnabvfSvb2feCbZIgebQC19bHA7ngw95e1uX0/xp/nqdp/t4nl73b6fHebovl3M79lu3PV1v88sy3dv1Mm9bO7XF9bH0PvYcet9z99fUDh/jkwtd14/d24dmm782y9Zs4nE5LfNL8/m1uf82N6fLul7@XM6/Nn@M62PePu6O@4Gq2x32vNt9aKZxnR7reJ@bn5qXZbuu42tzlN@H5j26Zd52avbpuN/G63V9la2Za/9PyN240cvl8Xmd238lpunsj13XmYfD//RwePdw/Obo@9i/zOP5efv9MUrZnufb7XLb3eaTBDy1OVLNfSMSokigUEQ86R9H0YkwRS8yUAx9kypFmUuFYhLJFGV1SiaRpAtNChSriCe1cJRYhCmJkzRQko@xkpjHQlk8xkxZzGOiIo6jxCP2MVAtkEHtPbFaOnISUGTyajKQl3WhIuRgAYVMSbyEBNchUpFdgzhzkEHWBXEmoyPW1UxOV4sviciLLxXz5c2XF18qEfF58WWigXnxpQscvHimIK69VcpVSjLnCsnpbFxGQiKaiUvk9WPUOrug1XCeKkbWCUdezRgFdQPSEBnkH1eSg95woSSWnKlUCOtcQgIcKZsMKgGFYk@ZIYMudyQbMFNOEI2KB3S6Ug06akUs@IL0MmwzOW0reiZZiH1EBBFtiAgxYKcADwHbeashbDw5r6M2w1HBmDRbCloB8klHhy8oBixZy8OkSWq5WA@XlAczQQuBijGiYysGYXKQzQTphFGHEnTMBaPTMWEycQcsDoJFsRXFzliu2CIXCkpCNlak1snIyUZOBjkAyHJRdIwcA4cNHGfgeAMnGDjRwMkAB/z8BzmpGjrO0IlAR7MRdLRZwgxA8tYWR9WDGcVcZDB09PQKOgxyOIIcB3BcBDjGjfZCgAlGjGYY7DoQYjRIIUbDEmKyBzEFwJQCYLSEIkMAMOwBDJrvcHIUmGDARAOmGDBswATIUAEMDkREP4QYBVRgyQZLxaiH3dkJEFa0R8JKMlZKgoCHrMmxlV5RqYZKNFQcGNHSCyN6b4hozAKJdocH@ziQq0qJhlwRo3XWOLcjknBXGJPJKg8fkTiBErCiZ0qqozcHMveohscl5y17JIgSO7sRcB7t1nF2o3yDpBgggACpW5ao8zsiGBmzg3EBGPTi/TEeX7Z5r49JK28uXpBne3V6cGN/5DH6xcH0@0domy63edcm/pm7p1amRd/@Bg)

Uses loess smoothing to interpolate between hard-coded data points.

The M and F curves are remarkably similar to each other after scaling (by 0.92x) - see the black & grey points on the graph - so the hard-coded points are taken from the mean of the two (scaled) curves, and then rounded to nice, short values.  The red line on the graph shows the interpolated values.

[image]

Unfortunately (for me), the scoring system of adding 1 to the mean-square-error strongly rewards reasonably-close fits, but doesn't give very much more reward for a *very*-close-fit, so the extra code-length here means that the overall score is still worse than Robin Ryder's looser fit to a normal distribution.

Comment: I probably should have tried a few approaches to get the scoring rules to the right balance of tension between length and error, but I also wanted to post this in time for me to incentivize some R answers...

Comment: To be fair, I think you've hit on a remarkably good balance.  I just like moaning.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), score 34.16

### 27 bytes, mean square error 0.21676 (rounded to 0.22)

```
#3(#2-#+Sqrt[(#2-#)^2+#4])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY1BC4IwGIbv/oqhEIlrbXOaEkInb0Vkt7Fg6SwhDUVP0W9fMyHoUt/le@F9eN5a9ldVy77Kpa6aIgUJyFQ7qCZXPPJRgEMIMGKrmEFAKUWRWFuG235xGAXxxIW@@ZRFKDBcmWjHnzt04XhZ2/X8Hd0T9Rwm3Jned1XT86M83xS3ANhtDvehKTgoubwoOI4IAMmSYCxMPR58jA2GhMRPYQYmg21/4g9Z@kemXw)

An unnamed function (which we will call `f` for the purposes of discussion) which takes two arguments (in this order), the age (an integer from 0 to 119) and the indicators for female or male in this form:

- indicator for "female": `Sequence[83.506,0.4794,222.8]`
- indicator for "male": `Sequence[80.596,0.4636,248.5]`

In Mathematica, `f[a,Sequence[b,c,d]]` is the same as `f[a,b,c,d]`; so `Sequence[b,c,d]` is almost exactly an ordered triple, except it's better for plugging into functions.

The above code implements the mathematical function

\$
f(a,b,c,d) = c\big( b-a + \sqrt{(b-a)^2+d} \big),
\$

where \$a\$ is the age and \$b,c,d\$ are numerical parameters used to optimize the fit with the data.

This specific form was motivated by my perception that the graphs of the data for each sex looked like a hyperbola with a slant asymptote to the left and a horizontal asymptote to the right, which can be brought into the above parametric form (here \$(b,0)\$ are the coordinates of the center of the hyperbola, \$2c\$ is the slope of the slant asymptote, and \$d\$ controls how far from the center the hyperbola bends). An evolutionary algorithm was then used to fine-tune the parameters for each sex separately; experiments suggest that there is a single local minimum for each set of data, as all attempts converged to very similar values for \$b,c,d\$.

(Technically, the entire function could have been used as the sex indicator, leading to the 4-byte solution `#2@#` with **score 6.1**. But many of the submissions could have done similar things.)